# I've started using this JavaScript pattern. Is there anything wrong with it?

Tags: javascript

I've started using this pattern in JavaScript. I'm not sure if I read about it specifically, or if I just conjured it up one day.

The format is...

```
var name = (function() {

    var init = function() {
       // Init something
       $('a').click(show);
    };

    var show = function() {
       // Show something
    };

    $(init);

})();
```

And here is a real world example...

```
var contactForm = (function() {
    var init = function() {

         if ( ! $('body').hasClass('contact')) {
            return;
         };

         var form = $('.contact #content form');

         form.validate({
              rules: {
                  'full-name': {
                      required: true
                  },    
                  'email': {
                      required: true,
                      email: true
                  },    
              },
              messages: {
                  'email': {
                      email: 'Please make sure this email is valid.'
                  }

          }
          }); 

    };

    $(init);

})();
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Why use the variables (*name, contactForm*) since you do not return anything from the function (*and you call it immediately*)? Why not just skip that part completely? or is it as a bookmark for you ?

Comment: @Gaby Just so I can clearly see what each function does, and it helps with debugging. I guess they could be comments, but then my stack trace would show some unnamed functions.

Answer (score 1):

No YUI actually call this the Module pattern and uses it in alot of their code.

You might even do the following within the anonymous function.

```
name = new init();
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  I actually do almost the same thing, but why are you calling `$(init)` instead of just `init()`?

Comment: Because I am using jQuery, and want it to be fired on DOM ready.

Comment: Ah.  I'm used to doing things a little differently and assumed you'd be wrapping multiple blocks within a single `$(function() {})` call.  Shame on me.  Continue.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a jQuery plugin written as a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).  You don't really need the `var name =` (extra global variable) and passing in the jQuery object is best practice in case of `$.noConflict()`.  See Ben Alman's [jquery-plugin-authoring](https://github.com/cowboy/talks/blob/master/jquery-plugin-authoring.js) talk for this and other interesting info.

```
(function($) {

    var init = function() {
       // Init something
       $('a').click(show);
    };

    var show = function() {
       // Show something
    };

    $(init);

})(jQuery);
```